# how can extract the href

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

how can extract the href content, im using python 2.7 and bs4

```
<h2 class ="product-card__title" >
    <a class ="link product-card__title-link" href="theping" >kik</a> 
</h2>
```

I have this code, im extracting the kik text easy, but i cant extract the href

```
find = soup.find_all('h2', {'class' : 'product-card__title'}, limit=None)
for a in find: 
    title = a.text.strip()
    print title
    url = a.find('a[href]')
    print url
```

this is a part code, title print perfect but url show me none.... some idea?

Comment: Never mind. I see that you're pulling the h2 not the a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for h2 in soup.find_all('h2', {'class' : 'product-card__title'}, limit=None):
    print h2.a['href']
```

Source: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Change below line:

**url = a.find('a[href]')**

to

**url = a.a[href]**